# angular ui-router multiple instances of named views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have multiple instances of a named view that are independent of each other. I would like for them to have states independently. If an action occurs in a view triggers a change of state, i don't want it to affect other views

```
<div>
    <a ui-sref="state1"></a>
    <div ui-view></div>
<div>
<div>
    <a ui-sref="state1"></a>
    <div ui-view></div>
<div>
<div>
    <a ui-sref="state1"></a>
    <div ui-view></div>
<div>
```

and the js:

```
$stateProvider
.state("default", {
  template: "<div ui-view></div>"
}
.state('state1', {
  url: "/state1",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
})
```

Say i have a dynamic and unbounded amount of top level div, how do i make the `<a>` target the right ui-view? I can't really name them all?

Comment: It's unlikely that this would work with ui-router. Why not use directives? What is your use case?

Comment: not entirely sure how directives solve this :( the idea is to create a card ui (eg each card represent a city) and when u tap on an elemrnt of the card (eg weather button) the card would show some other content (eg weather for that city). now if a card is in that second view (weather) and another card transitions into that state i dont want the first card to be affected (if the paris card is in weather view and london card transitions into weather, i dont want paris to be affected)

Comment: and i always want the cards to go back to the previous state ( go back to the city view)

Comment: ui-router is working using url, if you can't represent your states with url, then maybe ui-router cannot do what you want.